# A blank C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe keeps popping up.. R for windows Front-End

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, r

I'm using Windows 10 Pro. Every 20 - 30 seconds I notice a cmd.exe window that pops up briefly, takes focus away from my cursor and then disappears. This starts to happen shortly after I log in and persists through various reboots.

One time I managed to open task manager while the window was up. Doing so, I managed to get some details and I noticed that it had something to do with the taskSchedulerR package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/readme/README.html). It was trying to run some scheduled script. This is not a virus, as I was playing with this a few weeks back, but ultimately decided against using this package.

So, I uninstalled the package `remove.packages(taskscheduleR)`and now it is no longer in R addons, however, the annoying cmd window keeps popping up. Now the pop-up does not have anything to do with taskScheduleR, but instead references "R for Windows front-end". See the screenshot I managed to get.

Any help on getting this to stop would be appreciated. Hoping to avoid uninstalling/reinstalling RStudio.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Your going to need to remove the startup entry from the registry.  Safe Mode might prevent it from starting allowing you to find the entry.  Autoruns a Microsoft tool is also helpful

Comment: Tried removing the related task from Task Scheduler? See also: [Command Prompt Randomly Opens and Closes Quickly (Scheduled Task)](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-unknown-program-open-and-close-immediately/)

Comment: Thanks w32sh but my Task Scheduler is empty and I don't have Microsoft Office installed at all ( I probably should have mentioned that ). 

@ramhound, can you suggest where exactly I can find the start-up entry? I looked in the Run and RunOnce folders within the registry, but there is nothing relevant in there.

Comment: @ziptron - Something is starting the command prompt.  Sadly only you can find what that something is.  It likely is a service.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ramhound I downloaded Autoruns and it found the issue. It nicely highlighted a task that was trying to access a file which I had deleted.

Thank you, everyone, for your help.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/859975)

Comment: @Blackwood: Since the helpful ‘‘answer’’ was not an answer at all, but just a comment, this rule doesn’t entirely apply.  It’s generally accepted that, if one person posts a comment, another person is free to submit an answer based on that comment (of course, they must identify the source, as ziptron did). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  ziptron: Blackwood is right, up to a point; we prefer answers to be 99.44% technical.  Your first paragraph is OK (it might be better if you said more about what you found, but, if you believe that it’s a one-of situation that won’t apply to other people, then don’t bother); but you should avoid writing things like your second paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

As I have run through this a bunch of times Everybody is indeed correct about Finding this is task scheduler however its not noted as a cmd.exe its under "Chrome Loader" for me under 'Triggers' is says 'One Time After Trigger Repeat Every Ten Minutes' with PowewrShell execution bypass and its History is disabled So When you find The proper one is task scheduler disable it first then delete it from task scheduler. This should Fix

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).